# redirect to a route after api call in angular2

Tags: angular, router, subscribe

I need to redirect the user to a different component after processing (via api) the data user submitted through form.  Below is the code I tried.

**In component**

```
onSubmit(model){
  if(model.valid === true) {
    this.SharedService.postFormdata(model).subscribe(
       data  => { console.log(data)},
       error => Observable.throw(error);   
    );
    this.router.navigate(['PublicPage']);
  }
}
```

However, after call completed, its not redirecting to `PublicPage` component. Any help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class HeroesComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  onSubmit(modal): void {
    if(model.valid === true) {
      this.SharedService.postFormdata(model).subscribe(
      (data) => { 
        // Page redirect when getting response
        this.router.navigate(['/PublicPage']);
      }, 
      (error) => {
        console.log("err", error);   
      });
    }

  }

}
```

For better understanding read this docs: [Angular2 routing](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html)

Comment: THanks a lot. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 3):

First put your `error` outside of `data` block then If you want to redirect if it's success then add in

```
data => { this.router.navigate(['PublicPage']); }
```

Or if you want call anyhow, then use

```
() => {
        this.router.navigate(['PublicPage']);
}
```

So try like that:

```
onSubmit(model) {
    if (model.valid === true) {
        this.SharedService.postFormdata(model).subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.router.navigate(['PublicPage']); // ON SUCCESS
            },
            error => Observable.throw(error),
            () => {
                    this.router.navigate(['PublicPage']); //ANYHOW WILL CALL
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: ha, its a typo, error is outside of data block. Im trying now.