# Redirect to a route after api call in angular (using "this")

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, subscribe

This is similar to [redirect to a route after api call in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195784/redirect-to-a-route-after-api-call-in-angular2) but I want to use a class variable (`this.areaCode`) as part of the redirect or update a variable (`this.userInfoMessage`). Eg:

```
onSubmit(form: string): void {
    this.taskService.createTask(task).subscribe(this.taskCreated,this.handleError)
}
private taskCreated (resp: any) {
    console.log("Task created successfully",resp)
    this.router.navigate([`/areas/${this.areaCode}`]); // eg: "/areas/12" //"this" is of type SafeSubscriber, not my class
}
private handleError (error: any) {
    this.userInfoMessage="We've got errors here!"  //"this" is of type SafeSubscriber, not my class so the message is now bound
    console.log(error)
}
```

However I cannot fathom how to get a reference to the class in these functions. Do I need to use the `self=this` trick. If so, how?

Thanks

UPDATE

I have tried passing `this` into `this.taskService.createTask(task).subscribe(this.taskCreated,this.handleError).bind(this)` but `Property 'bind' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.`

UPDATE (2)

I guess the question is "how do I pass a reference into a subscription callback?"

Having read the linked Q if I want to subscribe passing in a reference to the current object I have tried using

```
var self= this
this.taskService.createTask(task).subscribe(this.taskCreated(self),this.handleError)
```

it does not compile.
I still have the callback defined as 
    private taskCreated (resp: any)

I don't think this is quite the same as the linked Q.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Before everyone votes to close, could you let me see if I can work out from the other answer what exactly I need to do pleasE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to `bind` the functions themselves, not the `Subscription` returned from the `subscribe` method.

```
onSubmit(form: string): void {
    this.taskService.createTask(task).subscribe(this.taskCreated.bind(this),this.handleError.bind(this))
}
```

Another way to do it would be in a closure:

```
this.taskService.createTask(task)
        .subscribe(
            (res) => this.taskCreated(res),
            (err) => this.handleError
         )
    }
```

**A niftier, cleaner, and less known way** to accomplish this in Typescript would be to instantiate the method itself with a fat arrow, leading to a lexical `this` that always refers to the class itself:

```
onSubmit(form: string): void {
    this.taskService.createTask(task).subscribe(this.taskCreated,this.handleError)
}

private taskCreated = (resp: any) => {
    console.log("Task created successfully",resp)
    this.router.navigate([`/areas/${this.areaCode}`]); // 'this' will refer to class!
}

private handleError = (error: any) => {
    this.userInfoMessage="We've got errors here!"  // 'this' will also refer to the class!
    console.log(error)
}
```

The official Typescript docs advise against function binding when possible, so I would use one of the second two solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
private handleError = (error) => {
   this.userInfo = "we have a problem here";
}
```